# Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int f dg$ different from Riemann integral $\int f g' dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

According to Wikipedia, the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int f dg$ maybe different from the Riemann integral $\int f g' dx$ when $g'$ is unbounded.

I hoped that by choosing $f(x) = \frac {1} {\sqrt x} $ and $g(x) = \sqrt x$ I could check this.

Then, on the interval $[0,1]$, the Riemann integral $\int \left(\frac {1}{\sqrt x}\right)^2dx$ is unbounded.

But it seems that the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $$\lim_{a\to 0}\varinjlim_{P \text{ partition of } [a,1]} \sum_{i \in P} \sup_{c_i \in [x_i, x_{i+1}]} \left(\frac {1}{\sqrt{c_i}} [\sqrt{x_{i+1}} - \sqrt{x_{i}}] \right) = $$

$$\lim_{a\to 0}\varinjlim_{P \text{ partition of } [a,1]} \sum_{i \in P} \left(\frac {1}{\sqrt{x_i}} [\sqrt{x_{i+1}} - \sqrt{x_{i}}] \right) = $$

$$\lim_{a\to 0}\varinjlim_{P \text{ partition of } [a,1]} \sum_{i \in P} \left( \sqrt{x_i}\frac {[\sqrt{x_{i+1}} - \sqrt{x_{i}}]}{x_i} \right) = $$

$$\lim_{a\to 0}\varinjlim_{P \text{ partition of } [a,1]} \sum_{i \in P} \left( \sqrt{x_i}[\sqrt{x_i}]' \right) = $$

$$\lim_{a\to 0}\varinjlim_{P \text{ partition of } [a,1]} \sum_{i \in P} 1 =\infty$$

is also infinite.

Is there a standard example of when the integrals differ? And maybe one where they are both finite, but different?

Comment: Try same example for $g$ but with $f(x)=1$.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson It seems like I'll get $\lim_{a\to 0}\varinjlim_{P \text{ partition of } [a,1]} \sum_{i \in P} \sqrt{x_i}$, which still explodes

Comment: For any function $g$ you should be able to check that $$\int_a^b dg(x)= g(b)-g(a).$$

Comment: @B.S.Thomson that works! If I don't put force a derivative from the third to the fourth line, I just get a telescoping sum. (I wonder what is wrong about using the directed limit to get that derivative) Does this mean that the Riemann-Stieltjes integral is reliant on the order of the reals (just like the Riemann integral, but unlike the Lebesgue integral)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @B.S.Thomson pointed out, the example works with $f(x)=1$

The problem is that taking a direct limit of a partition to make $$g(x_{i+1})-g(x_i) = |x_{i+1}-x_i|\frac {g(x_{i+1})-g(x_i)}{|x_{i+1}-x_i|} = g'(x_i)dx$$ only works if $g$ is of bounded variation.